# What would happen if too many people would call functions of a smart contract at the same time?

Tags: contract-invocation, gas

As a thought experiment, what would happen in the event too many persons would like to interact with many functions of a smart contract at the same time?

For example, could you approximate the max number of payable (with a message and some required value) function calls per hour for a small function of 4 lines of code? Would that simply be the time to mine a block, independently of the length gas price of the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry at all about this. "Performances" are not about "how many people call this", but in which order this is mined.

Indeed, lets say 100 000 persons call one single function in one contract and lets imagine all this transactions are mined in one block. The miner will mine every transaction ONE by ONE. So there is actually no "at the same time".

If your function is a simple call (not changing the EVM), then nothing is actually done because it does not change anything for the EVM, it's just requesting information.

Comment: Okay, so this means that multiple changes can be made in one block. I still wonder what's the practical limit. But yeah, this limit is maybe hard to test in practice. I'd still like a guess somehow.

Comment: The limit is the block gas limit. The size of one block is estimated in gas. If the transactions in one block use all the block gas, they will be mined in the next one (or in the uncle)